# When is CGI/FastCGI required and when it is not

Tags: django, angularjs, nginx, cgi, wsgi

This is propably a little noob-question, but I have read enough about CGI/FastCGI/WSGI and still not understood completely, so I decided to ask it.

First, I want to say what I have understood. I have understood that CGI is an interface program between a web server (for example Apache or NGINX) and a web server application (For example Python application). Also, I have understood, that you can simply by configuring the web server, serve a static file (html). You do not need CGI/WSGI for that. You need CGI or similar when you want to serve dynamic content, not just one file in some location. By serving I mean produce the html by some another program, which will then give it to the web server program

Then the thing I do not understand. Why doesn't angularJS require a CGI or similar? Is it because if deployed to for example Nginx, angularJS application can be served directly by serving the index.html file? And somehow magically, AngularJS handles everything (almost) after that? But if you have a Django based web application, then you do need a WSGI, which actually comes bundled in Django, so you do not need to necessary modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say anything useful about Django, but Angular simply lives in the client web browser. It doesn't need to do anything on a server, all program code is handled in JavaScript that runs on the client. So basically all your webserver has to do is serve a bunch of static files (html partial templates, javascript files, css etc) and Angular takes care of the rest.

Of course, once you start fetching dynamic data from the server through Angular, this situation may change, but in principle there's already a lot you can do with static json files, like for example the canonical angular phonecat tutorial shows.